# Get nested object from json in couchbase with N1QL

Tags: json, couchbase, sql++, nosql

I have following json as an entry in Couchbase:

```
{
    "messageType": "TRANS",
    "failCount": 0,
    "workOrderDetailMap": {
        "10873": {
            "requestDate": "20160715151239",
            "id": 10873,
            "responseDate": "20160715151305",
            "responseCode": 0,
            "status": "SUCCESS",
            "resultDocuments": [
                "xyz"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and I want to get `resultCode` field by N1QL query :

```
Select * from myproject where workOrderDetailMap.responseCode = 0;
```

I got 0 result.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need

```
select * from myproject where workOrderDetailMap.`10873`.responseCode = 0;
```

If you need to ignore the 10873:

```
select * from myproject where object_values(workOrderDetailMap)[0].responseCode = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you. but, my need is how parameterise 10873 value? it is different in each record.

Comment: Great! that's exactly what i was looking.. Thank you very much :)

Comment: @geraldss how to do join with like this nested array. e.g. JOIN ON KEYS users.id = groups.group_id_record[*].group_id? anything like this?